# Calling one method from another method and callback arguments

Tags: matlab, oop, events, callback, listener

I have a problem to define callbacks arguments and what [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html) says doesn't help me.

My first class:

```
classdef first < handle
   properties
       State = false
   end
   events
      Contact
   end
   methods
      function OnStateChange(obj,newState)
         if newState ~= obj.State
            obj.State = newState;
            notify(obj,'Contact');
         end
      end
      function follower(obj)
          while 1
              data=inputSingleScan(sessions_daq.NI_USB_1);
              if data>3
                  obj.OnStateChange(true)
              else
                  obj.OnStateChange(false)
              end
          end
      end
   end
end
```

My second class:

```
classdef second < handle
   methods
      function obj = answerer(obj_first,obj_third)
         addlistener(obj_first,'Contact',@obj.handleEvnt);
      end

      function handleEvnt(obj,obj_first,~,obj_third,~)
         if obj_first.State
            obj_third.tracker()
         end
      end
   end
end
```

My third class:

```
classdef third < handle
    methods
        function tracker(obj)
            %computations  
        end 
    end
end
```

Here is the error I get:

```
>> o_first=first;
o_third=third;
o_second=second(o_first,o_third);
>> o_first.follower
Warning: Error occurred while executing callback:
Undefined variable obj_third.

Error in second/handleEvnt (line 9)
            obj_third.tracker()

Error in second>@(varargin)obj.handleEvnt(varargin{:}) (line 4)
         addlistener(obj_first,'Contact',@obj.handleEvnt);

Error in first/OnStateChange (line 12)
            notify(obj,'Contact');

Error in first/follower (line 19)
                  obj.OnStateChange(true)

> In first>first.OnStateChange at 12
  In first>first.follower at 19
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please read the documentation. I've been telling you this several times yet it seems that you haven't. You especially need to read about [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Comment: The issue is that your anonymous function `@obj.handleEvnt` and your function definition `handleEvnt(obj, obj_first, ~, obj_third, ~)` *don't* match up. Your anonymous function only passes *three* inputs to `handleEvnt` and `handleEvnt` expects 5.

Comment: Where is defined here the number of inputs the anonymous function @obj.handleEvnt passes?

Comment: All `addlistener` callbacks by default pass two input arguments (the source and event data), then since you call it as `obj.handleEvnt` you add the current object as the first input. So essentially your anonymous function *actually* looks like this: `@(src,evnt)obj.handleEvnt(src,evnt)`. If you want to pass additional arguments you need to do that like: `@(src,evnt)obj.handleEvnt(src, evnt, other, arguments)`.

Comment: PS - Do you understand why in addlistener, the callback function has to be defined as an anonymous function (as it can be defined below, in the "program file")?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an anonymous function. There are a lot of ways to specify callbacks with various inputs (strings, cell arrays, etc.) it's just that anonymous functions are a very concise way of doing it. Also, they are used throughout MATLAB so it's good to get the hang of them. I have added a complete answer below summarizing what we have talked about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the way that you are defining your [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as your callback to `addlistener`. When the event is fired, [`addlistener` will provide your function with *two* inputs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html#inputarg_callback). These inputs are:

1. The object which fired the event
2. Some [`event.EventData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.eventdata-class.html) object which contains information about the event itself.

So when you specify a callback it *must* deal with these two inputs appropriately. In your case, you are calling a method of your class, so, you *actually* pass three inputs to your callback. The first input is the instance of the class and the other two are the ones provided by `addlistener`.

So in effect, your callback that you're defining is this

```
@(src, evnt)obj.handleEvnt(src, evnt)
```

So if you look at your function definition for the method `second.handleEvnt`, you will see that you have written it to expect *five* inputs.

```
function handleEvnt(obj,obj_first,~,obj_third,~)
```

The immediate reason that you are getting an error is because `obj_third` and the last input are *not* passed to this function by the callback that you have provided (since we said that it only passes *three* inputs).

To fix this you can either re-write your `handleEvnt` method to accept only three inputs.

```
function handleEvnt(obj, src, evnt)
```

Or you can rewrite your anonymous function to pass additional functions to the callback.

```
@(src,evnt)obj.handleEvnt(src, evnt, other, arguments)
```

In addition to the methods presented here using anonymous functions, you can also use *any* of the ways that MATLAB allows [callback functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html#buhztrr-8) to be defined.